# SQL query is taking more than 3 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$sql_combinaison_count = "SELECT pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang , pv.id_parametre_value, ic.id_combinaison , ic.prix_combinaison , ic.poid_combinaison, ic.actif_combinaison , ic.actif_genere , pv.actif_value , pipv.id_parametre_value as pipv_id_parametre_value
    FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."imp_combinaison_parametre_value_".$nom_domaines_imp[0]['id_nom_domaine']." cpv
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."imp_combinaison_".$nom_domaines_imp[0]['id_nom_domaine']." ic ON ic.id_combinaison = cpv.id_combinaison
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."imp_parametre_value pv ON pv.id_parametre_value = cpv.id_parametre_value
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."imp_parametre_value_lang pvl ON pvl.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."imp_parametre p ON p.id_parametre = pv.id_parametre
    LEFT JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."imp_product_impression_parametre_value pipv ON pipv.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value and pipv.id_product_impression = ".$_GET['id_product']."
    WHERE p.id_nom_domaine = ".$nom_domaines_imp[0]['id_nom_domaine']." And pvl.id_lang_domaine = ".$_GET['id_lang_domaine']." AND ic.id_product_impression = ".$_GET['id_product'].$sql_recherche."
    GROUP BY ic.id_combinaison,cpv.id_parametre_value
    ORDER BY ic.id_combinaison,p.id_parametre ";
```

The following query is taking too much time (more than 3 minutes). Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: Hello, do you have a way to access the execution plan? this way you can have hints about what part of the request needs to be reworked. maybe you can try to add indexes on the the columns the joins are using.
The number of records in each table could also be good to know.

Comment: My guess: The left joins, in combination with group by and order by. Do they have to be left join? Also, indices on foreign keys might help.

Comment: ps_imp_combinaison has 97290 lignes

Comment: ps_imp_combinaison_parametre_value has 705595 lignes